# Product variation dimensions and weight in WooCommerce not displaying on frontend

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce for WordPress, when you have a variable product, you can enter dimensions (length, widht and height) and weight for each variation.

However, the number I enter don't show up in frontend unless I also fill in the corresponding fields for the parent product.

The problem is, that whatever value I enter for the parent product is displayed on frontend when 'Select an option' is selected from the dropdown menu, and I don't want that. And if I enter '0' in the weight and dimension fields for the parent product or leave them empty, weight and dimensions are not displayed on frontend for the product variations either.

Comment: you can use custome fields for this

Comment: That will display in the additional information tab on frontend?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  You could try setting a value for the parent, and use CSS to hide the field.  Use jQuery's .change() method to change the CSS when a real value selected, something like jQuery('select#pa_label').change(function) { jQuery('#dimensions').show('fast'); });